# How to enable/disable rows in Microsoft Office Excel 2013

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel worksheet that contains, let's just say 3 columns (A, B, C).
rows in Column A are disabled until you choose something from Column C.
Column C has 3 options, let's just say `BIRD`, `CAT` and `DOG`.
When I choose any item in column C, all the rows in Col A will be enabled.

Rows in column B is for length validation of the rows in column A.

I am doing this because there is a formula in Column B that validates the length of Column A. For example, if I choose 'BIRD' the formula for column B will have a rule that the length should only be equal to let's say 5.

In Column C, I just need to select any item from the list. I hope this clears the scenario.

How do I do this?

Thanks you guys!

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Subject says `enable/disable rows` and your question is focusing on columns A, B, C. What is your question?

Comment: Hi @Nelly27281, I already edited the question.

Comment: What do you mean by column C has three options? Are these values in list or in three cells in column C?

Comment: Column C has 3 values in a list. When I select an item from the list, the rows in column A will be enabled. Thank you!

Comment: So you want A1 to be locked until an entry is mage in C1?

Comment: "rows in column A" is very confusing. Do you have a single cell in Column C that has a drop down list? And when the cell is "Bird" you want the corresponding Cell of the same row in Column A to become unlocked? Unhidden? Un-somethinged?

Comment: Is that 3 values - first value in C1, second in C2, third in C3.  Or is it all in C1 with a data validation drop-down list, or is it in an ActiveX listbox control placed in cell C1 or is it a Form listbox control placed in column C?  All can contain 3 values in a list.  Just asking... :)

Comment: I edited the question. hope it can clear things up Thank you guys!

Comment: @JNevill yes i have a single cell in column C that has a dropdownlist.

Comment: Post the screenshot of your data. Your question is not clear yet.

Comment: hope this helps:

First, Select an item from a list on single row in Column C first before enabling the rows in Column A

Second. Rules for in column B depends on the item selected in the list:
example:
    a. BIRD: Characters in Col A should be 10 characters.
    b. CAT: Characters in Col A should be 8 characters.
    c. DOG: Characters in Col A should be 6 characters.
Third,  Column B will show an YES or NO if the characters are valid.

I don't know how to post the screenshot.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook, the list is just in C1.

Comment: I was able to post the screenshot of what i am trying to do.

Comment: What's the point in locking/unlocking column A?

Comment: Hi Nelly, i've been asking the same question, it's part of a request. They need to choose first before they can input in column A so that they can determine what rule to follow. just like i said, there is a certain rule for every item. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of locking and unlocking `Column A`, consider just hiding the column based on the selection on `C`. Either way you will have to use VBA, but going with Hiding and Unhiding means less code and easier work downstream as more logic enters the sheet.

In VBA, click on the worksheet that this is taking place in. In there put the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Check to see what changed. If it was "C1" then go ahead
    If Not (Intersect(Target, Range("C1")) Is Nothing) Then

        'If the value in C1 is "Bird" then unhide Column A
        If Target.Value = "Bird" Then
            Range("A").Hidden = False

        'Otherwise Hide column A
        Else
            Range("A").Hidden = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The only confusing part here is that `If Not(Intersect(Target...` line. What's happening here is that every time this tab is changed (like a cell is changed on the tab) this macro will fire. It will then test to see if the cell that was changed is `C1`... we just do that with the confusing `If Not(Intersect(Target...` line because folks that write VBA are sadists.

You could change this to lock/unlock `Column A` as well. That would require you to remove protection from the tab, unlock `Column A`, then re-protect the tab. Or, in the event that it needs to be locked: Unprotect the tab, lock `Column A`, and then reprotect the tab. You can record yourself doing this with the macro recorder to see the code, but you can guess it's a bit more verbose then just hiding and unhiding.

Comment: I appreciate you helping me out on this. I have to see this one first. And will let you know.